# Terraform replace function on module output variable

Tags: regex, terraform

This is for a Front Door configuration setup.
This output variable, `module.storageacc.primary_web_endpoint`, contains the following string:
`https://url.server.com/`

I need pass this value to the `host_header` and `address` fields in the backend_pools configuration. The key is that the value needs to only include the host name without the `https://` or the trailing `/`.
This regex works for me on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) to strip the unwanted string characters, but in Terraform it doesn't work at all.

```
(https://)|(/)
```

```
host_header = replace(module.storageacc.primary_web_endpoint,"(https://)|(/)","")

address = replace(module.storageacc.primary_web_endpoint,"(https://)|(/)","")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the syntax for adding regex values in terraform is to add a "/" in at the start and end of the regex value.

corrected code:

host_header = replace(module.storageacc.primary_web_endpoint,"**/**(https://)|(/)**/**","")

address = replace(module.storageacc.primary_web_endpoint,"**/**(https://)|(/)**/**","")

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction to @lgpana's answer: if your url ever contained a path the regex would replace all `/`, not just trailing. This can be avoided by using the line end `$` like so:

```
host_header = replace(module.storageacc.primary_web_endpoint,"/(^https://)|(/$)/","")

address = replace(module.storageacc.primary_web_endpoint,"/(^https://)|(/$)/","")
```

(while I was at it I also specified that the https should be at the start with `^`)